# Convert iso format datetime string to datetime object in Python

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, python-3.6

I am facing a issue while converting a iso format datetime string to datetime object in Python 3.6 without loosing the timezone info.
The string is like this.

```
2021-07-04T00:00:00+02:00
```

I tried datetime.datetime.strptime method. But unable to set the correct format string.

```
datetime.datetime.strptime( "2021-07-04T00:00:00+02:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
```

If the datetime string is in this format it works:

```
datetime.strptime("2021-07-04T00:00:00+0200", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
```

But in this format, don't work:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime( "2021-07-04T00:00:00+02:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
```

And I have the datetime in this format:

```
2021-07-04T00:00:00+02:00
```

Comment: What is the issue you're facing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date)

Comment: What it is the problem? Maybe if you write also what you tried (with actual result, and expected result), it will help us to understand better your problem. Python3.6 now is *old*. If you can update to Python 3.7 (or later), you have *fromisoformat* functions in datetime module

Comment: @MrFuppes I am not getting how to get the object using strptime method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Python 3.7+ you can use `datetime.datetime.fromisoformat()` function, also
`strptime("2021-07-04T00:00:00+02:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")` will work fine.

For Python 3.6 and lower the time zone format is expected to be `±HHMM`. So you will have to transform the string before using `strptime` (remove the last semicolon).

For example:

```
tz_found = t_str.find('+')    
if tz_found!=-1 and t_str.find(':', tz_found)!=-1:
    t_str = t_str[:tz_found+3] + t_str[tz_found+4:tz_found+6]
result = datetime.datetime.strptime( t_str, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
```

Comment: But I want to retain the timezone info.  strptime("2021-07-04T00:00:00+0200", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z") works in Python 3.6  But if there is colon in time zone (like +02:00) it not works

Comment: OK means, need to do the things manually. There is not any direct way!